# How to send a bulk email in Java spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

```
     mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                int i =0;
                System.out.println(stringArray[i] +" Email");
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo(stringArray);
                //message.setTo(InternetAddress.parse(",rahul@mailinator.com"));
                message.setFrom(
                    new InternetAddress("infinitydeveloper2020@gmail.com", "Grand DMS")
                );
                message.setSubject(mailData.getSubject());
                //message.setBcc("Grand DMS");
                message.setText(htmlText, true);
            }
        };
        mailSender.send(preparator);
```

This is my code. Please let me know how to send a bulk mail in batch process.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMailSender is extension of MailSender and JavaMailSenderImpl is implementation of JavaMailSender which has method JavaMailSender#send(MIMEMessagePreparator[]). So create an array of your MIMEMessagePreparator and send in batch.